# Updating an object with Realm without a Primary Key

Tags: react-native, realm

In my React-Native app, I need to update some objects but I can't do like the tutorial :

```
realm.write(() => {
 // Create a book object
 realm.create('Book', {id: 1, title: 'Recipes', price: 35});

 // Update book with new price keyed off the id
 realm.create('Book', {id: 1, price: 55}, true);
});
```

Because my objects don't have a primary key (and i don't want them to have primary key)

There is **my try** :

```
this.state.realm.write(() => {
  this.state.realm.create('Bills', {type: this.state.billType,
  creditor: this.state.billCreditor, month: this.state.billMonth,
  year: this.state.billYear, price: this.state.billPrice}, true);
});
```

But this try obviously create an another object ^^

Is someone have an idea for my problem please? Thanks for all =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I used UUID as Primary key ^^"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-uuid

Answer (score 0):

Currently Realm doesn't support updating objects without primary keys. See [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2632) GitHub issue.

If you really want to achieve this, you will have to delete the object from Realm and then adding it with the updated values.

However, I wouldn't recommend this method. Creating a primary key in most cases is the optimal solution, so you should reconsider using it. The built in update method will in most cases have a better performance than any method you could write without using primary keys.